# How to insert data into mysql through spark DataFrames using Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe

I am quite new to spark and dataframes and I am going nuts searching on internet how to insert data into mysql table using dataframes (Spark-Java). I found lots of stuff on scala but there are very little information provided on Java.

I followed the steps provided in the link http://www.sparkexpert.com/2015/04/17/save-apache-spark-dataframe-to-database/. It looked pretty simple but when tried it myself ,I faced issues in creating correct dataframe schema and inserting data in table with **autoincrement** field.

**mySql table(Person) schema**

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| person_id  | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| first_name | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name  | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| gender     | char(1)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Java Code**

```
DataFrame usersDf= sqlContext.jsonFile("data.json");                
    usersDf.printSchema();
    usersDf.insertIntoJDBC(MYSQL_CONNECTION_URL, "person", false);
```

**data.json**

```
{"person_id":null,"first_name":"Judith1","last_name":"knight1","gender":"M"}
{"person_id":null,"first_name":"Judith2","last_name":"knight2","gender":"F"}
{"person_id":null,"first_name":"Judith3","last_name":"knight3","gender":"M"}
{"person_id":null,"first_name":"Judith4","last_name":"knight4","gender":"M"}
```

When I run the above code, Dataframes are created with schema given below:

```
root
|-- first_name: string (nullable = true)
|-- gender: string (nullable = true)
|-- last_name: string (nullable = true)
|-- person_id: string (nullable = true)
```

Whereas schema should be

```
 root
|-- person_id: integer (nullable = false)
|-- first_name: string (nullable = true)
|-- last_name: string (nullable = true)
|-- gender: string (nullable = true)
```

So because of wrong schema created I got the following error.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value: 'Judith1' for column 'person_id' at row 1
```

Please let me know how to solve this problem.I know there is some minor problem only but I couldn't find it.Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like that the schema is created on the alphabetical order of column names, maybe you can search about this on the web.